# JSF panelGroup - 1 span for all?

Tags: java, jsf, layout

I'm wanted to use a panelGroup to group my inputs and their labels

e.g

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{jsfServicesError.errorClass}" binding="#{jsfServicesError.myComponent}">
<h:outputLabel for="company" id="companyLabel" value="#{bundle.IDENTITY_COMPANY} * :"/>
<h:inputText id="company" label="#{bundle.IDENTITY_COMPANY}" value="#{manager.uiUser.attribute.company}" required="true" styleClass="text normal">
    <f:validateLength minimum="3"/>
</h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

If I put some more other panelGroups after one I get as result 1 span class which includes all other inputs and labels. Is this working as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with Mojarra 1.2_14 on Tomcat 6.0.20:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<f:view>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>SO question 2057438</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="foo">
                    <h:outputLabel for="input1" value="label1" />
                    <h:inputText id="input1" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="foo">
                    <h:outputLabel for="input2" value="label2" />
                    <h:inputText id="input2" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="foo">
                    <h:outputLabel for="input3" value="label3" />
                    <h:inputText id="input3" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

And the output is just as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>So question 2057438</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="j_id_jsp_452028652_1" name="j_id_jsp_452028652_1" method="post"
            action="/playground/test.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="j_id_jsp_452028652_1" value="j_id_jsp_452028652_1" />
            <span class="foo">
                <label for="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input1"> label1</label>
                <input id="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input1" type="text" name="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input1" />
            </span>
            <span class="foo">
                <label for="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input2"> label2</label>
                <input id="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input2" type="text" name="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input2" />
            </span>
            <span class="foo">
                <label for="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input3"> label3</label>
                <input id="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input3" type="text" name="j_id_jsp_452028652_1:input3" />
            </span>
            <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="j_id1:j_id2" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your problem lies somewhere else. Maybe you actually didn't look in the generated HTML output or you expected that the multiple panelgroups would be aligned under each other. If the latter is true, then you need to add `layout="block"` to the `h:panelGroup` so that it will render a `<div>` instead. A HTML `<div>` element is by default a **block** element while the HTML `<span>` element is an **inline** element. Roughly said, HTML block elements like `<form>`, `<div>`, `<table>`, `<ul>`, etc implicitly adds a newline after so that any next element visually starts at a new line.

If you're still on the ancient JSF 1.1 or older where the `h:panelGroup` doesn't have the `layout` attribute, then you'll need to add CSS `display: block` to the class associated with the `<span>` element.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer balus. I've found the problem: its the binding of the panelgroup. What I'm trying to achieve is: Binding the panelGroup to a backking bean and if 1 child has an error message: change the css style of the panelGroup element.

Comment: You cannot bind different components to **one** same property. They would override each other. As to your actual problem, look for other solutions, this really isn't a nice way. Post a new question if you want help/assistance.

Comment: Yes I noticed that - thats giving me this "strange" behaviour. :)

Comment: You may get some ideas out of my answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938551/associate-inputtexts-to-outputlabels-for-validation Just substitute `h:outputLabel` with `h:panelGroup` to get it to work in your requirement.